# How to set size quota for folder in some network storage?

Tags: linux, filesystems, network-share, quota, network-storage

Server has multiple users, every user has its own folder and can upload files.

**How to prevent abuse and set a size limit for the user folder?** It should allow disk space optimization - users should be able to share unused space.

**What network file storage systems can provide such option?** Ability to mount as a standart unix file system is important, I can't use Riak for example.

Operating system can be any POSIX - compatible, I use Ubuntu-server because it's easy to set up, but any other also will be fine.

P.S.

Also (but it's optional and not a hard requirement) it would be nice to have such property. If data get lost - it should get lost completely but in one place (whole user folders should get lost but for small amount of users), than small piece but in many-many places (one or two files but in many-many user folders).

It is possible to set such quota on the application-level by checking size before storing file, but I can't use it because in my case file upload done not directly by application but via some third-party module I don't control.

Comment: So you're not even going to mention an operating system or any actual details in any way?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about it, OS should be any POSIX - compatible, currently I use Ubuntu-server.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I have not found anything to arbitrarily control a given directory.  The larger NFS network appliances, such as Netapp and Isilon, provide a way to control quotas at basically a top level directory situation.  Where I work, we use a number of project directories and can control the total quota for the directory and a specific user quota under this directory.  It seems to work fine.